# jQuery get only top level elements

Tags: jquery, nested

I need to get only the first matched elements from my tree (if element was found no need to go deeper). The problem is that this element can be wrapped into nested divs, so I can't use `>` selector.
My code is like this:

```
<div id="root">
    <div class="sub">I need this element</div>
    <div>
        <div class="sub">I need this element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub">
        <div class="sub">I don't need this element</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can't find solution :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't use the child selector, try

```
$('.sub:not(.sub .sub)')
```

This selects only those `.sub` elements which are not descendants of other `.sub` elements.

Alternatively:

```
$('#root .sub').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parentsUntil('#root', '.sub').length === 0;
});
```

which also works if `#root` is inside a `.sub`.

*Edit:* Or see @RightSaidFred's comment for this case.

Comment: You could also modify your selector to handle cases where `#root` is nested in a `.sub`: `$('#root .sub:not(#root .sub .sub)')`. Unfortunately either way you're not getting the `querySelectorAll` benefit.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Good point, but why would jQuery not use `querySelectorAll`? `:not` is a valid CSS3 selector.

Comment: @FelixKling: `:not()` is indeed valid as long as you don't have a complex selector inside. `:not(.sub)` is valid, but `:not(.sub .sub)` is not. :(

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Thank you for that information, I just [looked it up](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) and you are right. Too bad :(

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
$('.sub').parent().not('.sub').children().css('color', 'green');
```

which is a verbose version of:

```
$('.sub:not(.sub .sub)').css('color', 'green');
```

Edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jli1/yZw3z/)

Comment: No, it can't find nested div :(

Answer (score 2):

You would need the element or class which is above the first div, then specify {parent-selector} >

```
$('#root > div.sub').click(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var level = $('#root'),
    subs;

do {
    level = level.children();
    subs = level.filter('.sub');
} while( els.length && !subs.length )
```

The `subs` variable will hold the result.

It's an efficient approach, and will work if your `#root` happens to have a `.sub` ancestor.

You could easily make it into a reusable function.

```
function firstLevelOf( root, selector ) {
    var level = $(root),
        result;

    do {
        level = level.children();
        result = level.filter(selector);
    } while( els.length && !result.length )

    return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var subs = firstLevelOf( '#root', '.sub' );
```

Comment: This is probably the better way.